# Error al cifrar string con AES128 utilizando OpenSSL en C++

Tags: c++, encriptación, openssl

Estoy teniendo problemas con los últimos 32 caracteres (16 bytes) del mensaje cifrado que estoy generando con la biblioteca OpenSSL y el algoritmo AES 128 en modo CBC, estos son los datos que estoy usando:

```
Message in Hex = "7b22494443223a2232363930393439376434222c22444553223a2256656e74616d656e7564656f222c22414d4f223a3530302c22444154223a313530383233303035383730362c22524546223a302c22434f4d223a312c22545950223a31392c2276223a7b224e414d223a2252616661656c56616c656e7a75656c614172656e6173222c22414343223a2235383732313233343536373836303132222c2242414e223a34303132372c22545943223a332c22444556223a22353532373139323132382f30227d7da"
Key128 in Hex = "dadf11e74d014a62d73ccadd9591442a"
Initialization Vector in Hex = "cab9da8940cd7dc9510c7249fe47c6e6"
```

Este es mi código que estoy implementando:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>

#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

using namespace std;

/* AES key for Encryption and Decryption */
const static unsigned char aes_key[16]={0xda, 0xdf, 0x11, 0xe7, 0x4d, 0x01, 0x4a, 0x62, 0xd7, 0x3c, 0xca, 0xdd, 0x95, 0x91, 0x44, 0x2a};

/* Print Encrypted and Decrypted data packets */
void print_data(const char *tittle, const void* data, int len)
{
    printf("%s : ",tittle);
    const unsigned char * p = (const unsigned char*)data;
    int i = 0;

    for (; i<len; ++i)
    {
        printf("%02X ", *p++);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main( )
{
    /* Input data to encrypt */
    unsigned char enc_out[235]={0x7b, 0x22, 0x49, 0x44, 0x43, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x22, 0x32, 0x36, 0x39, 0x30, 0x39, 0x34, 0x39, 0x37, 0x64, 0x34, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x44, 0x45, 0x53, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x22, 0x56, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x75, 0x64, 0x65, 0x6f, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x4f, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x35, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x35, 0x30, 0x38, 0x32, 0x33, 0x30, 0x30, 0x35, 0x38, 0x37, 0x30, 0x36, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x52, 0x45, 0x46, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x30, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x43, 0x4f, 0x4d, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x54, 0x59, 0x50, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x31, 0x39, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x76, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x7b, 0x22, 0x4e, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x22, 0x52, 0x61, 0x66, 0x61, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x56, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x7a, 0x75, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x41, 0x72, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x73, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x41, 0x43, 0x43, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x22, 0x35, 0x38, 0x37, 0x32, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x36, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x42, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x34, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x37, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x54, 0x59, 0x43, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x33, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x44, 0x45, 0x56, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x22, 0x35, 0x35, 0x32, 0x37, 0x31, 0x39, 0x32, 0x31, 0x32, 0x38, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x22, 0x7d, 0x7d, 0xa};

    /* Init vector */
    unsigned char iv[16]={0xca, 0xb9, 0xda, 0x89, 0x40, 0xcd, 0x7d, 0xc9, 0x51, 0x0c, 0x72, 0x49, 0xfe, 0x47, 0xc6, 0xe6};
    //memset(iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    /* Buffers for Encryption and Decryption */
    unsigned char dec_out[400];
    unsigned char aux_out[400];

    memset(dec_out, 0, sizeof(dec_out));
    memset(aux_out, 0, sizeof(aux_out));

    /* AES-128 bit CBC Encryption */
    AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, sizeof(aes_key)*8, &enc_key);
    AES_cbc_encrypt(enc_out, dec_out, sizeof(enc_out), &enc_key, iv, AES_ENCRYPT);
    /* AES-128 bit CBC Decryption */
    memset(iv, 0x00, AES_BLOCK_SIZE); // don't forget to set iv vector again, else you can't decrypt data properly
    AES_set_decrypt_key(aes_key, sizeof(aes_key)*8, &dec_key); // Size of key is in bits
    AES_cbc_encrypt(dec_out, aux_out, sizeof(enc_out), &dec_key, iv, AES_DECRYPT);

    /* Printing and Verifying */
    print_data("\n Original ",enc_out, sizeof(enc_out)); // you can not print data as a string, because after Encryption its not ASCII

    print_data("\n Encrypted",dec_out, sizeof(enc_out));

    print_data("\n Decrypted",aux_out, sizeof(dec_out));

    return 0;
}
```

Aparentemente, solo el final de la cadena es el incorrecto (los últimos 32 caracteres) el resto está bien, he investigado un poco y algunos comentarios apuntan a que tiene que ver el error a el tipo de rellenado del texto que esta configurado (padding), pero de acuerdo con lo que leo, ese rellenado ya esta con PKCS5 (que es el relleno que necesito, de hecho) así que no puedo ver cuál es el error al cifrar los datos, también he intentado hacerlo por bloques pero no resulta bien. Estos son los resultados:

```
El cifrado esperado (Correcto) = EFC063DD33406D424D359809695D0B1E2D65027E803962C6A115DF7CCABEEB0C8C358830E556ED23943FA4F02E6461D235EF913CFCE5519F7CE2279DD07D3C4054D045827D5D7D9FE94DA3C5B718A24E79539B3FFC1E68E4C3FF441EEA176F61EE3D7B33B622E3069D95815F6407FBC79342BB972A2DDE4E50FDE9302BDE4409B7D2BD388AB6A043B9EF236D982937D8537F954564FF4134BD8A6EAB994FE4C29E9DC4E54D53A561A4688C45C90961EDB1763B6EF6C86B593C7E16FDF35C49CE16B1E6948BB1EAE6A8692326A019960B

La salida del programa (Incorrecto) = EFC063DD33406D424D359809695D0B1E2D65027E803962C6A115DF7CCABEEB0C8C358830E556ED23943FA4F02E6461D235EF913CFCE5519F7CE2279DD07D3C4054D045827D5D7D9FE94DA3C5B718A24E79539B3FFC1E68E4C3FF441EEA176F61EE3D7B33B622E3069D95815F6407FBC79342BB972A2DDE4E50FDE9302BDE4409B7D2BD388AB6A043B9EF236D982937D8537F954564FF4134BD8A6EAB994FE4C29E9DC4E54D53A561A4688C45C90961EDB1763B6EF6C86B593C7E16FDF35C49CE608E3F73FC8E3DDF1D3BCF40B3DFACD00B732A9FCC10F6E0FB18E126A1C21A082D7A4F053F131A9329474D
```

Entiendo que el código tiene mejoras y al parecer el descifrado no esta funcionando pero de momento lo que me interesa es el cifrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás mezclando las variables:

```
print_data("\n Encrypted",dec_out, sizeof(enc_out));
//                        ~~~~~~~         ~~~~~~~
```

Entiendo que la llamada debería ser

```
print_data("\n Encrypted",dec_out, sizeof(dec_out));
//                                        ^^^
```